# cannot declare variable ‘cs’ to be of abstract type when creating derived template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, derived-class, point-cloud-library

I want to write my own `PCL class` and for this I have derived my class from `:pcl:Features class`.
When I try to create an object of my class I get this error and I don't know what I am doing wrong:

`/home/.../PCL_SANDBOX/sandbox_main.cpp:85: error: cannot declare variable ‘cs’ to be of abstract type ‘CloudSubtractor<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::PointXYZI>’ 
   CloudSubtractor<PointT,PointT> cs;`

I want to create the object like that;

```
CloudSubtractor<PointT,PointT> cs;  // this is where the error happens. main.cpp:85
```

My template class header is as follows.

```
#ifndef CLOUDSUBTRACTOR_H
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/feature.h>
#define CLOUDSUBTRACTOR_H

template <typename PointInT, typename PointOutT>
class CloudSubtractor: public pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT> 
{

public:

    typedef boost::shared_ptr< CloudSubtractor<PointInT, PointOutT> > Ptr;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< const CloudSubtractor<PointInT, PointOutT> > ConstPtr;
    typedef typename pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::PointCloudOut PointCloudOut;
    typedef typename pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::PointCloudConstPtr PointCloudConstPtr;

      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::feature_name_;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::getClassName;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::indices_;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::input_;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::k_;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::search_radius_;
      using pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::search_parameter_;


    CloudSubtractor () :
          pointIncrement_ (0.25)
          {
            feature_name_ = "CloudSubtractor";

          }

    inline void setPointIncrement(float inc) {pointIncrement_ = inc;}
    inline float getPointIncrement() {return pointIncrement_;}
    void applyDummyFunction(typename pcl::PointCloud<PointInT>::Ptr cloud_out);



    virtual ~CloudSubtractor ()
    {

    }

protected:
    /** \brief The grid spacing in x,yz, direction. Smaller values lead to to larger and denser point clouds (default: 0.25). */
    float pointIncrement_;
    /** \brief An input point cloud describing the surface that is to be used for nearest neighbors estimation. */


    using pcl::Feature<PointInT,PointOutT>::surface_;
};


template<typename PointInT, typename PointOutT>
void CloudSubtractor<PointInT, PointOutT>::applyDummyFunction(typename pcl::PointCloud<PointInT>::Ptr cloud_out)
{

    pcl::copyPointCloud(*surface_,*cloud_out);
    for (int i=0; i< surface_->size(); ++i){
        cloud_out->points[i].x = surface_->points[i].x + 3;
        cloud_out->points[i].y = surface_->points[i].y + 5;
    }
}
#endif // CLOUDSUBTRACTOR_H
```

The feature.h file from which I am deriving can be found here: http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/feature_8h_source.html

Comment: From a quick search of the linked header, `pcl::Feature::computeFeature` is a pure virtual function which you do not seem to override.

Comment: So basically I can rename my 'applyDummyFunction' to computeFeature and it should work? I have hardly any experience with virtual functions.